# Bulk Sorting and Data Extraction from Scanned PDF

Tags: pdf, image-processing, ocr

I work in a small company that will start dealing with some data processing, as an additional service to its core business. We need to accomplish two things for a large number of scanned PDF files (good quality) of bank transactions:
1. Sort the PDF files in folders according to the account number;
2. Extract data from some of them, depending on the transaction type.

The transaction files are very variegated: 35 different banks, about 20 different transactions for each bank and 4 languages. More or less, we are talking about 2,800 templates...

The first step would be to recognize the bank, then the account number and then the transaction type (and so forth). If transactions are of type X, simply move the files somewhere, otherwise read on and extract a few fields.

We checked some commercial solutions but they are way to expensive for our budget, so I'm wondering I might find a solution by putting together several pieces (either Windows or Linux).

I'm used to hack my way through problems, so any crazy idea is welcome!

Thanks

Comment: If the fonts and stuff aren't to different, maybe this  **https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract**  I know the nuance Omnipage SDK is like $5000 but you get what you pay for.  Prepare your self for a learning curve, or wall you have to climb for tesseract.  It is free.

Comment: I'm using an ugly mix of ABBYY FineReader Corp and sevral Python scripts with decent results. However, it's still far from usable in production. Tesseract seems like an idea, but I need ABBYY to pre-process the image getting rid of skewness, rotations, etc. Still searching for a better overall solution.

Comment: www.Blender.org has, blender,  an it has a python scripting support system also, and it has many image processing abilities.  You might want to check that out.

Comment: @chris there's plenty of free software for "getting rid of skewness, rotations, etc." OCR is the only difficult part.